# set text over an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have an android application where I take a picture with the camera phone...and put the picture in an `ImageView`.Next what I wanna do is to set a text on the bottom of this picture.

Until now I've done something like:

```
   ImageView image;
   bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                       .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
   image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Can u please help me and tell me what should I do next?Some code would be nice!

EDIT:XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:weightSum="1">
 <Button
android:id="@+id/logoButton"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:text="LogoButton"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" 
android:layout_width="224dp">
</Button> 

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageview"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </ImageView>
```

UPDATE:this is how I use the camera:

```
   ....onCreate(){
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File image=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PhotoContest.jpg");
        camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(image));
        imageUri=Uri.fromFile(image);
        startActivityForResult(camera,1);
                      }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){

    case 1:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
              Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
              getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
              image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
              ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
              Bitmap bitmap;
              try {
                   bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                   .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                   image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                   Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                          .show();
                  Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
              }
          }
         else 

         if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(EditPhoto.this, "Picture could not be taken.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

1.I'm not sure that this trick with FrameLayout puts the text on my Image...because further more I want to upload the photo.Will the text still be there if I upload the photo on a website???

2.I have another problem with the camera...after I take a picture...it displays it horizontaly and not full screen..>DO u know how could I fix that?

Comment: of course I have an XML.I'm not getting any Null Exception!

Comment: I've edited my question with the XML.So what next?

Comment: @george I've edited my answer to take into account your wish to directly see the Camera's preview (instead of an ImageView)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either build a new image made of the picture + the text overprited or show both as layers on the screen. This depends of whether you would like to save and reuse this image with the text overprinted.

As I understood your question, this is not the case here (please let me know if I am wrong, and I'll update this answer). So `FrameLayout` is your friend: it allows showing graphical components as overprinted frames:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView ...your picture, with the desired attributes />
    <TextView ...your text, with the desired attributes />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can surround the `ImageView` and the `TextView` by `LinearLayout`s to make them come with other components such as buttons, etc. Simply, you have to consider each component directly included in `FrameLayout` as a new frame that you can design as any usual layout.

*Further to your comment to xevincent's answer on this page:* If instead of an `ImageView` you would like to display the preview of your Camera, you can define your own `SurfaceView` that will take care of the `Camera`'s lifecycle:

```
package com.example;

// imports

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeSurfaceHolder();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // call Camera.open(); and Camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); here
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Call Camera.setParameters() and Camera.startPreview() here 
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Call Camera.stopPreview() and Camera.release() here
    }

    private void initializeSurfaceHolder() {
        // This initializes the SUrfaceHolder of your Camera
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }  
}
```

And then, use this class in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.example.CameraView         
        android:id="@+id/previewcam"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView ...your text, also with the desired attributes />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) and place your image and text accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, create ImageView and TextView with orientation vertical and set the text in textView !

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) is about a layout trick but the example shows you exactly what you want.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

    android:padding="12dip"

    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"

    android:text="Golden Gate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yes,but the thing is that my ImageView comes from camera is not something drawable;)